# In maven, is it possible rebuild a module?

Tags: maven, pom.xml

In maven, is it possible to rebuild a module?  Suppose I have modules A, B, C.

Is it possible in module A, B, and C to somehow each build module X?  For example, I want my build flow to be like this:

build A
build X
build B
build X
build C
build X

Before flaming me, I know this is not the best practice but I am constrained by other factors.  I have tried using  moduleX  and defining dependency in the A, B, and C pom but X only gets build once.  Thanks.

Comment: I do not have very much experience with Maven, but that sequence is strange, as Maven tries to build (or reuse already built) modules in the order they're needed. I think it would be better if you just tell us something more about your requirements / constraints.

Comment: Well, part of my constraint is from higher up.  I need to show him if this is possible or impossible.  Basically, I am copying files on the fly and need to rerun a module (module x) to build multiple zip files.  Having said that, I don't want to derail the discussion to other alternative methods.  As I said, I know it is not the best practice and it is not my design.

Comment: What do you mean by `rebuild` then? Can you elaborate more? I thought you meant recompile, but now you mention copying files and running again your module X. What are you exactly expecting to be able to do?

Comment: `mvn -pl moduleYouWouldLikeToBuild clean package` has to be called from the root of the hierarchy. The order is defined by the dependencies between the modules. It does not matter what the constraint is. That's the way it is. About what you are talking is a Maven Multi Module build which is extactly intended to build modules which have dependencies between each other. The order is automatically determined by the build system. Furthermore what you like is not the best practice it's more a misunderstanding of the concept of Maven and build tools in general.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try having 3 parent modules, each only containing a pom, for each of A, B, and C?

In each of these parent poms they would build they're corresponding module as well as X. 
So for example, you'd have Aparent which would have A and X specified as modules to build. You'd also have the same for Bparent and Cparent.

These 3 parent modules would need to be built by a 'super' pom then, which would contain these three modules (Aparent, Bparent and Cparent). I think you might need to introduce this hierarchy in order to get around the issue.

Best of luck with it

Comment: Thanks, I will give that a try.  Each of the module A, B, and C does have its own pom.  A, B, and C inherits from another xml file that contains most of the logic for copying files on the fly.  I have added module X to that xml file and it doesn't work.  Module X only get build once.

Comment: Looks like it doesn't work. As soon as A and B both define module X, I get the error: Two or more projects in the reactor have the same identifier, please make sure that <groupId>:<artifactId>:<version> is unique for each project